# Validar valores de un array (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, validación, php8, laravel-9

Tengo un *`select`* en el que se puede seleccionar múltiples *`opcions`* para posteriormente insertarlos en la DB después de pasar una serie de validaciones.

Lo que quiero es que cada valor del select sea único en la columna name de la tabla genres.

Este es mi select en el *front-end*:

```
<select class="form-select" data-tags="true" name="name[]" multiple>
    <option value="Action">Action</option>
    <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
    <option value="Animated">Animated</option>
    <option value="Biography">Biography</option>
</select>
```

Este es un ejemplo de los datos recibidos del *front-end*:

```
{
    "_token": "dMQ2OICxsCMSU4LdQrgyI2G0FXR5FxtTqmeYaWNU",
    "name": [
        "Action",
        "Adventure"
    ],
    "type": "movie"
}
```

Este es mi *validate form request*:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Admin;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class GenrePostRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|array|unique:genres',
            'type' => [
                'required',
                Rule::in(['movie','tv'])
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
public function store(GenrePostRequest $request)
{
    foreach ($request->name as $value) {
        Genre::create([
            'name' => $value,
            'type' => $request->type
        ]);
    }

    return redirect(Route('admin.show.genres'))->with('success', 'Genre upload successful.');
}
```

Esta es mi tabla de `genres`:

| id | name | type | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Action | movie | 1 |
| 2 | Animation | movie | 1 |

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda brindada.

Comment: Podrías dar un ejemplo de lo que querés hacer? No termino de entender la pregunta.

Comment: Y también de lo que has intentado y el error (O errores) que recibes

Comment: Ese es el problema. No se como hacerlo posible.

Comment: Si uso ```'name' => 'required|array|unique:genres'``` en el validador, lo valida pero solo el primer valor del array. No los valida todos. Si consigo poner varias opciones donde la primera ya existe y las demás no. Retorna el error de que ya existe pero no me retorna las que son correctas al controlador para guardarlas.

Comment: Me parece que estás equivocando la funcionalidad de la "validación". Si algún campo falla la validación, esa información NO llega al controlador. No podes hacer que se descarte lo que no te sirve, pero que pase lo que si te sirve. Eso NO es una validación (al menos no de ese tipo). Tendrías que implementar esa lógica directamente en el controlador. Insisto, el `formRequest` es para que solo se ejecute la lógica del controlador si TODOS los campos son válidos.

Comment: En este enlace tienes la respuesta.
https://laravel-array.com/validar-un-array-en-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

No creo que haya mas problema que tirar un loop y validar elemento por elemento de la forma que quieras. Por ejemplo algo así:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->name as $daigual) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'name.*' => 'unique:genres,name'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Yo acabo de testear esto para asegurar que funciona:

Hago un post para verificar varios emails en un array. Así que tiro un post con este body:

```
{
"cosas": ["ferr@gmail.com", "peep@gmail", "pepereder@feger.es", "fe.es", "ferterter@feegeetuer.es"]
}
```

Controller:

```
public function testCosa(Request $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->cosas as $cosa) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'cosas' => 'required',
                'cosas.*' => 'email'
            ]);
        }

        return [
            'status' => 1     
        ];
    }
```

Output que me tira Laravel:

```
{
    "message": "The cosas.3 must be a valid email address.",
    "errors": {
        "cosas.3": [
            "The cosas.3 must be a valid email address."
        ]
    }
}`
```